# Help to replace var type in this Smart Contract

Tags: solidity

Which's the type of **agent** variable? How can I remove the type **var** (to remove the warning in my code). Please ignore the comments.

```
    uint nonce;
    struct Agent {
        uint idAgent;
        uint[] O_preferences;
    }
    mapping(address => Agent) public agents;
    address[] public agentsInfo;
    
    /// @notice Crea un nuevo agente con sus parámetros
    /// @param _address dirección del agente 
    /// @param _idAgent id del agente
    /// @param _O_Preferences preferencias del agente
    function setAgent(address _address, uint _idAgent, uint[] _O_Preferences) public {
        var agent = agents[_address];
        agent.idAgent = _idAgent;
        agent.O_preferences = _O_Preferences;
        agentsInfo.push(_address) -1;
    }
```

Last question: what does that **-1** mean (on the last line)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `agent` is a reference to an item from `agents`:

```
var agent = agents[_address];
```

Now `agents` is a mapping from address to `Agent`.

So you can replace var with `Agent` (with storage access)

```
Agent storage agent = agents[_address];
```

---

The `-1` at the end of `agentsInfo.push(_address) - 1` does nothing.

In old solidity version `.push(..)` returned the new array's length, so `.push(..) - 1` is the position where the new item was stored.

In this particular case since the result is not assigned to anything it serves no purpose. If you remove `- 1` it semanticly works the same.